# robots.txt file in Angular application hosted with .Net Core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have hosted a web application built with Angular 5 server side rendering and hosted within .Net Core on a Windows server. I have uploaded a robots.txt file in the root directory of the server. However, when I try to browse https://sample.com/robots.txt it doesn;t load the file.

I have a feeling where Angular is trying to parse the URL instead of server. Please advise.

Comment: Where do you serve client files in server ? are they in the wwwroot ?

Comment: yes, got it. thanks for the heads up. Its fixed now.

Comment: Glad that you got you'r point. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @Arash above in the comment, the file should be uploaded in the `wwwroot` folder and not the root folder of the server.